# Authentication Error when using Flask to connect to ParseServer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parse-platform, flask, parse-server

What I am trying to achieve is pretty simple.

I want to use Flask to create a web app that connects to a remote Server via API calls (specifically ParseServer).
I am using a third-party library to achieve this and everything works perfectly when I am running my code in a stand-alone script. But when I add my code into the Flask I suddenly can't authenticate with the Server

> Or to be more precise I get an 'unauthorized' error when executing an API call.

It seems to me that in Flask, the registration method used by the APi library is not remembered.

I tried many things of putting the registration and initialization code in different places in Flask, nothing worked.

I asked a similar question in the Github of the [Library](https://github.com/milesrichardson/ParsePy/issues/147) with no help.

So I guess I have **two questions** that could help me solve this

1) Where should I put a registration method and import of the files from this library?
&

2) What can I do to identify the issue specifically, eg. to know precisely what's wrong?

Here's some code

The Flask code is here

```
@app.route('/parseinsert')
def run_parse_db_insert():
    """The method for testing implementation and design of the Parse Db
    """
    pc = ParseCommunication()
    print(pc.get_all_names_rating_table())
    return 'done'
```

The ParseCommunication is my Class that deals with Parse. If I run ParseCommunication from that script, with the same code as above in the **main** part, everything works perfectly.

I run the Flask app with dev_appserver.py from Google App Engine.

My folder structure

```
/parseTest
  /aplication
   views.py
  app.yaml
  run.py
```

My run.py code

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'lib'))
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'application'))
import aplication
```

Let me know what else I could provide to help out.

Thank you in Advance

EDIT:

A stack trace as requested. 
It's mostly related to the library (from what I can say?)

```
ERROR    2016-09-28 06:45:50,271 app.py:1587] Exception on /parseinsert [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/aplication/views.py", line 34, in run_parse_db_insert
    name = pc.get_user('testuser1')
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/aplication/parseCommunication.py", line 260, in get_user
    return User.Query.get(username=uname)
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/parse_rest/query.py", line 58, in get
    return self.filter(**kw).get()
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/parse_rest/query.py", line 150, in get
    results = self._fetch()
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/parse_rest/query.py", line 117, in _fetch
    return self._manager._fetch(**options)
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/parse_rest/query.py", line 41, in _fetch
    return [klass(**it) for it in klass.GET(uri, **kw).get('results')]
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/parse_rest/connection.py", line 108, in GET
    return cls.execute(uri, 'GET', **kw)
  File "/home/theshade/Devel/ParseBabynames/parseTest/lib/parse_rest/connection.py", line 102, in execute
    raise exc(e.read())
ResourceRequestLoginRequired: {"error":"unauthorized"}
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace of the error?  Can you add logging to each function to see how far it gets?  You have interchanged spelling: "aplication" vs. "application".  Check that.

Comment: @GAEfan Thank you for responding.

I edited the stack-trace into the question. From what I can say it's mostly related to the Python SDK/API library I am using. But maybe you can read out more out of it then me. 

Again, thank you for your help

Comment: Again, back to the interchanging of "aplication" and "application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse requires keys and env variables.  Check this line:

`API_ROOT = os.environ.get('PARSE_API_ROOT') or 'https://api.parse.com/1'`

Your error is in line 102 at:

`https://github.com/milesrichardson/ParsePy/blob/master/parse_rest/connection.py`

Before you can parse, you need to register:

```
from parse_rest.connection import register

APPLICATION_ID = '...'
REST_API_KEY = '...'
MASTER_KEY = '...'

register(APPLICATION_ID, REST_API_KEY, master_key=MASTER_KEY)
```

Comment: So before you answered I discovered that the line you posted it was different in the code of the parselibrary in Flask as there wasn't the or part present.

So after I updated the library directly from github it was working on a new project but not the old one.

Turns out that in old project I am importing a ModelClass which also uses Users class from the library before I import the ParseCommunication class which contains the registration.
Once I switch this up it works.

Thank you for your help and effort @GAEEfan

Comment: I am trying something very similar. I am getting the same trace, but I suspect this issue is the rest_key. What I have been able to find is that the open source parse server dose not use the REST_API_KEY. Have you found a work around?